# How to optimize checking if one of the given arrays is contained in yet another array

Tags: java, android, algorithm, optimization

I have an array of integers which is updated every set interval of time with a new value (let's call it data). When that happens I want to check if that array contains any other array of integers from specified set (let's call that collection). 
I do it like this:

- separate a sub-array from the end of data of length X (arrays in the collection have a set max length of X);
- iterate trough the collection and check if any array in it is contained in the separated data chunk;

It works, though it doesn't seem optimal. But every other idea I have involves creating more collections (e.g. create a collection of all the arrays from the original collection that end with the same integer as data, repeat). And that seems even more complex (on the other hand, it looks like the only way to deal with arrays in collections without limited max length).

Are there any standard algorithms to deal with such a problem? If not, are there any worthwhile optimizations I can apply to my approach?

EDIT:
To be precise, I:

- separate a sub-array from the end of data of length X (arrays in the collection have a set max length of X and if the don't it's just the length of the longest one in the collection);
- iterate trough the collection and for every array in it:

  - separate sub-array from the previous sub-array with length matching current array in collection;
  - use Java's List.equals to compare the arrays;

EDIT 2:
Thanks for all the replays, surely they'll come handy some day. In this case I decided to drop the last steps and just compare the arrays in my own loop. That eliminates creating yet another sub-array and it's already O(N), so in this specific case will do.

Comment: Your last sentence is the reason for your perceived problem. You need to create no sublists in order to find out if they were equal.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [KMP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). It's been designed with String matching in mind, but it really comes down to matching subsequences of arrays to given sequences. Since that algorithm has linear complexity (O(n)), it can be said that it's pretty optimal. It's also a basic staple in standard algorithms.

dfens proposal is smart in that it incurs no significant extra complexity iff you keep the current product along with the main array, and can be checked in O(1), but it is also quite fragile and produces many false positives and negatives. Just imagine a target array [1, 1, ..., 1], which will always produce a positive test for all non-trivial main arrays. It also breaks down when one bucket contains a 0. That means that a successful check against his test is always a necessary condition for a hit (0s aside), but is never sufficient - aka with that method alone, you can never be sure of the validity of that result.

Answer (score 1):

look at the rsync algorithm... if i understand it correctly you could go about:

you've got a immense array of data [length L]

at the end of that data, you've got N Bytes of data, and you want to know whether those N bytes ever appeared before.

precalculate:

for every offset in the array, calculate the checksum over the next N data elements.
Hold that checksum in a seperate array.

Using a rolling checksum like rsync does, you can do this step in O(N) time for all elements..

Whenever new data arrives:

Calculate the checksum over the last N elements. Using a rolling checksum, this could be O(1)

Check that checksum against all the precalculated checksums. If it matches, check equality of the subarrays (subslices , whatever...). If that matches too, you've got a match.

I think, in essence this is the same as dfen's approach with the product of all numbers.

Comment: I don't want to "know whether those N bytes ever appeared before" but whether within those N bytes are M bytes from some defined set. So a checksum won't do (that was nice in dfen's approach - it allows to eliminate those M bytes that surely aren't part of N).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can keep product of array to for immediate rejections.

So if your array is `[n_1,n_2,n_3,...]` you can say that it is not subarray of `[m_1,m_2,m_3,...]` if product `m_1*m_2*...` = M is not divisible by product`n_1*n_2*...` = N.

Example

Let's say you have array

```
[6,7]
```

And comparing with:

```
[6,10,12]

[4,6,7]
```

Product of you array is `6*7 = 42`

`6 * 10 * 12 = 720` which is not divisible by 42 so you can reject first array immediately

`[4, 6, 7]` is divisble by `42` (but you cannot reject it - it can have other multipliers)

In each interval of time you can just multiply product by new number to avoid computing whole product everytime.

Comment: Clever. But is there some nice way to deal with too large integers? Even long can be too small with just a few data points (my don't have large values, but still long won't be enough). I could just check some numbers, create a collections of arrays that fit and proceed, but that's something I wanted to avoid.

Comment: I think you could overcome the problems with the overflow by using calculation in a residue class ... but I'm not up to the task to do that now ;-)

Comment: @DThought I guess, residues won't work. The problem with them is that multiplication by `x` modulo `N` is an invertible operation for all `x` coprime to `N`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't have to allocate anything if you simulate `List`'s `equals` yourself. Just one more loop.

Similar to dfens' answer, I'd offer other criteria:

- As the product is too big to be handled efficiently, compute the GCD instead. It produces much more false positives, but surely fits in `long` or `int` or whatever your original datatype is.
- Compute the total number of trailing zeros, i.e., the "product" ignoring all factors but powers of 2. Also pretty weak, but fast. Use this criterion before the more time-consuming ones.

But... this is a special case of DThought's answer. Use rolling hash.